# Rounding corners of scatterview item - Microsoft surface SDK

Tags: wpf, xaml, pixelsense, scatterview

I have an image overlaid on the scatterview item. The scatterview item contains stackpanel and few textblocks. On overlaying and putting the main window's background as transparent, I can still see the corners which do not gel well with the image.

I am using surfaceusercontrol to add surface items in scatterview. The code is below:

```
<s:SurfaceUserControl x:Class="Models.ModelItemControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008" Width="110" Background="Transparent">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/models_card_150-01.png" Opacity="1.0" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Viewbox >
    <StackPanel MaxWidth="250" MinHeight="300">
    <TextBlock Name="ItemTitle" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Visible" Padding="2" />
    <Image Name="ItemImage" Margin="5,5,5,5"  Visibility="Visible" MaxHeight="100"/>
    <TextBlock Name="ItemDesc"  Margin="5,5,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Visible" Padding="2" />
    <s:SurfaceToggleButton Checked="ItemInfo_Checked" Unchecked="ItemInfo_Unchecked" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Display more info</s:SurfaceToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</s:SurfaceUserControl>
```

I want a method to clip the corners to round shape instead of rectangular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had posted on MSDN also, the link to the answer is posted below:

[Rounding corners of scatterview item-MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/9ed9acad-8843-475d-86c8-d8b304dfda65)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what you see is the ScatterViewItems shadow and not your UserControl. You can remove the shadow in code-behind using this:

```
item.ApplyTemplate();
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
item.ShowsActivationEffects = false;
Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome ssc;
ssc = item.Template.FindName("shadow", item) as Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome;
ssc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

This assumes item being your ScatterViewItem. Have a look at the ScatterViewPuzzle from the SDK to see how to make a custom shape for a ScatterViewItem.

Comment: I tried this code where i am creating each scatterview item and replaced item=this, but it didnt work. The corners look rounded when seen normally on the background, however when i move it over another scatterview item, the border shown is again rectangle and so is the show. By using your code, i could remove the shadow but the corners still showed up rectangular shape when overlapping.